# Method is undefined error

Tags: java, object, methods

I am trying to write a code that uses a menu to call on a method in a different file that is in the same folder.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BugTest {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("==Bug Solution==");
      System.out.println("Enter the bug's intial position: ");
      int pos = input.nextInt();
      Bug bug = new Bug(pos);
      System.out.println("--Menu--");
      System.out.println("1) Change Directions");
      System.out.println("2) Move Bug");
      System.out.println("3) Exit");
      int menu = input.nextInt();
      while (menu != 3) {

         switch(menu) {
            case 1: turn();
            break;
            case 2: move();
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid Response");
            break;
          }
         menu = input.nextInt();
       }


    }  
}
```

I get an error on case 1 and case 2 saying the method is undefined for type BugTest.

Comment: I think you want your bug to move and turn, not your bugtest, so you need to tell the compiler that by specifying *what* is doing the moving and turning (i.e. `bug.turn()`, `bug.move()`

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In a `main` method you should always call methods from a given `Object` (given that they are not `static` methods).  Otherwise the program doesn't know which `object`'s method it's supposed to call. For example create class Bug:

```
public class Bug{

   public Bug() {

  } 

  public void moveLeft() {
     // add code here
  } 

}
```

Then in your `main` method call the method by creating an instance of class `Bug`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bug myBug = new Bug();

    myBug.moveLeft() ; // calls the method of the myBug object
}
```

In your case the problem can be solved by calling `bug.turn()`  and `bug.move()` instead of just `turn()` and `move()`.